# XSLT: изменить имя узла

Tags: xslt

Здравствуйте. Есть такой xml:

```
<Сообщение>
    <Document.ВидДокумента>
        <РеквизитДокумента>ЗначениеРеквизитаДокумента</РеквизитДокумента>
    </Document.ВидДокумента>
</Сообщение>
```

Результат преобразования должен стать таким

```
   <Сообщение>
        <Document.ВидДокумента>
            <РеквизитДокумента xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CatalogRef.Спр">ЗначениеРеквизитаДокумента</РеквизитДокумента>
        </Document.ВидДокумента>
    </Сообщение>
```

Не пойму, каким должен быть текст преобразования :(
Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: В обоих документах имена узлов одинаковы, ничего не поменялось.

Comment: может я не совсем верно сформулировал вопрос. в первом случае у нас <РеквизитДокумента>Значение......." а во втором "<РеквизитДокумента xmlns:xsi=....длинная строка.....Спр">Значение

Comment: суть как раз и заключалась в том, чтобы добавить эту длинную строку, которая должна вложиться между <РеквизитДокумента..... и ...>Значение

Comment: Тогда почему в вопросе "изменить имя узла"? Так и пишите: "добавить атрибут".

Comment: нашел способ добавить атрибут и значение
`код`
<xsl:variable name="xmlns_xsi" select="'xmlns:xsi=@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance@ xsi:type=@CatalogRef.Склады'"/>
<xsl:template match="DocumentObject.ЗаказПокупателя/СкладГруппа">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:attribute name="xmlns_xsi">
<xsl:value-of select="$xmlns_xsi"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
`код`
но проблема в том, что атрибуту не могу назначить имя "xmlns:xsl", а значение атрибута так же не могу задать "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CatalogRef.Склады"

Comment: `xmlns:xsi` - это объявление _пространства имён_ с префиксом `xsi`. Соответственно, `xsi:type` - это _атрибут_ с именем `type`, относящийся к этому пространству имён.

Answer (score 0):

`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` - это объявление *пространства имён*. Этому пространству имён назначен алиас `xsi`.

`xsi:type="CatalogRef.Спр"` - это *атрибут*. У него префикс `xsi`, значит он относится к тому пространству имён.

Ваша задача - добавить к элементу атрибут с нужным пространством имён. Объявление при этом создастся автоматически! Его не нужно делать вручную.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="РеквизитДокумента">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">
        <xsl:text>CatalogRef.Спр</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Здесь используется [Тождественное преобразование](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform). Документ просто копируется как есть.

Для элемента с именем `РеквизитДокумента` определён отдельный шаблон, в котором в него добавляется нужный атрибут. Пространство имён добавится автоматически.

Обратите внимание, где находится объявление пространства имён в самом xslt.

Comment: ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ СПАСИБО!!!!!