# XSLT: добавить атрибут у которого есть спецсимволы

Tags: xslt

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь. Есть XML вида

```
 <Message>
     <Document>
         <SomeData>SomeValue</SomeData>
     </Document>
 </Message>
```

Нужно преобразовать этот XML к виду

```
<Message>
    <Document>
        <SomeData Attr="Text">SomeValue</SomeData>
    </Document>
</Message>
```

где Attr будет иметь значение 
{xmlns:xsi}

а Text будет иметь значение 
{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CatalogRef.SomeAnotherData}
(значения находятся между фигурных скобок)

Текстовка преобразования, который это делает, НО БЕЗ СИМВОЛОВ : И " такой (здесь символ : заменен на _    а символ " на @)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:variable name="xmlns_xsi" select="'xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance@ xsi:type=@CatalogRef.SomeAnotherData'"/>
<xsl:template match="Message/Document/SomeData">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:attribute name="xmlns_xsi">
<xsl:value-of select="$xmlns_xsi"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Как нужно написать файл преобразования, чтобы на выходе получился текст с символами : и " ???

Comment: Не нужно создавать однотипные темы. Лучше отредактировать предыдущий вопрос.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [XSLT: изменить имя узла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810621/xslt-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b0)